# Bootstrap: Cannot Create Responsive Columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

this is my  first time posting, so pardon any posting oddities on here.

I'm attempting to create responsive columns with Bootstrap to follow along with a course and I've been doing so in Codeply. I am supposed to create responsive columns that meet the following parameters:

1. On a **Large** Screen Size: 6 Columns
2. On a **Medium** Screen Size: 4 Columns
3. On a **Small** Screen Size: 1 Column

I have some screenshots attached that show what's happening when I try to make this occur on a large and medium screen (based on the device icons on the bottom right). On a small screen, the columns take up the screen's width as they're meant to, but I think that's happening by default rather than on account of something I'm doing.

Any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: Code pasted!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey; border: 1px solid;"> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey; border: 1px solid;"> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey; border: 1px solid;"> 
    </div>
   
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey; border: 1px solid;"> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey; border: 1px solid;"> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:grey; border: 1px solid;"> 
    </div>
    
</div>
```

[Code Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKU5w.png)
[Code Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77tIQ.png)

Comment: Any chance you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73465449/edit) and either post those images as text, or direct links to your Codeply sandbox? Images are static; it's really hard for us to interact with it and help debug your issue. Your column sizes _look_ correct to me; `col-lg-2` will result in 6 columns (12 / 2) on `lg` and above, `col-md-3` will result in 4 columns (12 / 3) for `md`, and `col-sm-12` will result in 1 column on `sm` and below. Typically they are listed in opposite order though, `col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2`, but that _shouldn't_ matter 

Comment: Tried that without success. :( I apologize for the tiny images, I'm unable to embed or paste anything until I participate here a bit more. All I have are links.

Comment: Nice! And now I can copy and paste that into a Codeply Sandbox and illustrate that your [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLnKK.png) [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQuvn.png) [as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0v1X.png); On LG/XL, you get 6 columns, on MD you get 4, and on SM/XS you get 1. The icons on the bottom seem to be off by 1 pixel for the breakpoints.

Comment: Oh thank you! Now it works for me too. I appreciate the patience and help. :)